# docker: DIND rootless container - how to change default gateway

Tags: routes, docker-in-docker, rootless

How can I change the default root in [docker in docker rootless container (DIND-rootless)](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) as `ip route change default via 10.10.8.1 dev net1` is not permitted?

The DIND-rootless has a second interface, exclusively connected to this container. I want all traffic flowing through this interface, so I have to change the default gateway, how can I achieve this?
Moreover, how can I prove this as traceroute is not permitted as well?